# Why I can't read multiple barcode with pyzbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to use pyzbar to read multiple barcode, however it seems like I can't read multiple instead of only one big bounding boxes.[image]

Comment: For example, you can cut the barcode yourself and pass the image to pyzbar. Or, although it is not pyzbar, there seems to be such an issue. [How can I scan a page with multiple barcodes? #4](https://github.com/brettatoms/zbar-ctypes/issues/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `pyzbar.decode` it will decode **all** 1D barcodes in your image. For example:

[image]

```py
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image

for bar in decode(Image.open('benchmark.jpg')):
    print(bar.data)
```

will print out

```
b'12345678'
b'12345678'
b'0000123456784'
```

However in your case all barcodes *are identical* so pyzbar just returns a list with a single element. It would work if they were *different* however.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have tested with multiple different barcodes it seems like work, however, looks like the pyzbar by default only can recognize 0,90,180,270,360 degree of barcodes, maybe I need to find a way to recognize variant degree of 1D-barcodes